# Python 2.7.4, does anyone know why this is not working?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, rot13

The following code is for one of my excercises to pass the subject,

This is my code:

`rot13=raw_input("Please write your text! ")`

This is where i ask the user for a text

`for i in range(len(rot13)):`

And in this part I check the text letter by letter with for.

```
 if rot13[i]=="a":
     rot13[i]="n"
 elif rot13[i]=="b":
     rot13[i]="o"
 elif rot13[i]=="c":
     rot13[i]="p"
 elif rot13[i]=="d":
     rot13[i]="q"
 elif rot13[i]=="e":
     rot13[i]="r"
 elif rot13[i]=="f":
     rot13[i]="s"
 elif rot13[i]=="g":
     rot13[i]="t"
 elif rot13[i]=="h":
     rot13[i]="u"
 elif rot13[i]=="i":
     rot13[i]="v"
 elif rot13[i]=="j":
     rot13[i]="w"
 elif rot13[i]=="k":
     rot13[i]="x"
 elif rot13[i]=="l":
     rot13[i]="y"
 elif rot13[i]=="m":
     rot13[i]="z"
 elif rot13[i]=="n":
     rot13[i]="a"
 elif rot13[i]=="o":
     rot13[i]="b"
 elif rot13[i]=="p":
     rot13[i]="c"
 elif rot13[i]=="q":
     rot13[i]="d"
 elif rot13[i]=="r":
     rot13[i]="e"
 elif rot13[i]=="s":
     rot13[i]="f"
 elif rot13[i]=="t":
     rot13[i]="g"
 elif rot13[i]=="u":
     rot13[i]="h"
 elif rot13[i]=="v":
     rot13[i]="i"
 elif rot13[i]=="w":
     rot13[i]="j"
 elif rot13[i]=="x":
     rot13[i]="k"
 elif rot13[i]=="y":
     rot13[i]="l"
 elif rot13[i]=="z":
     rot13[i]="m"
```

`print rot13`

Does anyone knows why this is not working? I do not want to do it with encode.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you want to achieve? What is the expected and observed output, respectively? Please read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Right off the bat, I see that you're trying to swap out a char for another by doing `rot13[i] = "..."`. You can't do this in Python. Consider turning the string into an array first using `list(rot13)`. But first, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I was trying to ask user for a text, and i would print it with rot13 characters. I actually did it when i make rot13 a list with list(rot13)  and after this i did:
keimeno="",
for i in range (len(rot13)):,
    keimeno=keimeno +rot13[i],

print keimeno
.
So it would print it like a text and not like a list.

Comment: Why don't you iterate the letters and build a new string variable? Also, try to use mapping from key (letter) to its value (its log1, since you know the dictionary size). You can iterate the string as a list of chars, `for char in rot13:`

Comment: Im not going to write this code for you, it's your task, try to write a code as simple as you can in maximum performance. Having map from key to value and building net string can be achieved in log(n) and in one line, two lines with making this more readable, three without using dictionary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

First, you're trying to assign a character to a string, but strings are immutable, so you can't swap out chars using `=`. Second, you don't need to hardcode each character and its mapping. You should use the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator (`%`).

The basic solution is to loop through each char, turn it into a number, add 13 to it, and turn it back into a character. You'll have to consider the case where your input is "z" and the resulting character lies beyond the alphabet. That's where you'll have to use the modulus operator to force the character to wrap around.

Here's an example:

```
def rot13(string):
  result = []
  for char in string:
    shiftBy = 65 # uppercase 'A'
    if char.islower():
      shiftBy = 97 # lowercase 'a'

    newChar = chr(((ord(char) + 13 - shiftBy) % 26) + shiftBy)
    result.append(newChar)

  return ''.join(result)

print rot13("abcXYZ")
```

`ord` converts a character to its numeric representation (e.g. `'a'` becomes `97`)

`chr` does the reverse computation (e.g. `97` becomes `'a'`)

Comment: Or use `string.maketrans` to make the mapping table and the `translate` method of `str` to accomplish any given transformation as a one-liner in the most efficient possible manner (On Py3, it would be `str.maketrans` to make the table).